# Router::extensions(['json']) has no effect on the ErrorController

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

My goal is to have exception messages converted to JSON when requested (via headers and/or filename extension). According to [*JSON exception in cakephp 3*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43790672/json-exception-in-cakephp-3), this needs to happen in `src/Controller/ErrorController.php`. If I simply add `$this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json')` to `beforeFilter()` it works fine, but then again, I should be forcing JSON only when JSON is explicitly requested.

- I started by adding `Router::extensions(['json'])` to the top of my `routes.php` following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29695919).
- Then I created a test action `/foo/bar.json` throwing a `new BadRequestException('hello')`.
- Lastly, debugging in `src/Controller/ErrorController.php`:

  ```
  public function beforeRender(Event $event)
  {
      parent::beforeRender($event);

      $this->viewBuilder()->setTemplatePath('Error');

      debug($this->getRequest());exit;

  }
  ```

When I request it, I can see that the extension isn't parsed at all:

```
object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest) {
    [protected] params => [
        'controller' => 'Foo',
        'action' => 'bar.json',
        // …
        '_ext' => null,
    ]
```

Trying `$this->getRequest()->is('json')` also returns `false`.

When I add `debug(Router::extensions());exit;` to the top of `config/routes.php`, nothing happens. Could this mean the file isn't read at all? Or is that because the exception aborts the execution before it even gets there?

How do I force JSON error messages when explicitly requested?

Relevant code:

- `config/routes.php`:

  ```
    <?php

    use Cake\Core\Plugin;
    use Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder;
    use Cake\Routing\Router;
    use Cake\Routing\Route\DashedRoute;
    use Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware;

    Router::extensions(['json']);
    debug(Router::extensions());exit;

    Router::defaultRouteClass(DashedRoute::class);

    Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
        $routes->registerMiddleware('csrf', new CsrfProtectionMiddleware());
        $routes->applyMiddleware('csrf');
        $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);

        $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);

        $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
    });

    Router::prefix('abc', function ($routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
    });
    Router::prefix('def', function ($routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
    });
    Router::prefix('ghi', function ($routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
    });
    Router::prefix('api', function ($routes) {
        $routes->prefix('jkl', function ($routes) {
            $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
        });
    });
    Router::prefix('mno', function ($routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
    });
    //Plugin::routes();
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [`setExtensions()`](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/config/routes.php#L85) inside a corresponding scope instead of the global call
2. **If using a prefix, configure that exact prefix**.
3. Clear the cache: `bin/cake cache clear_all`

If done right, there will be **no need** to additionally configure `src/Controller/ErrorController.php` [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43790672/json-exception-in-cakephp-3).

Working code:

```
Router::prefix('myprefix', function ($routes) {
    $routes->setExtensions(['json']);
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

That's it. Requests having the `.json` extension within `/myprefix` to an action that throws an exception will be returned as JSON.